# How to fix? ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I already have my log4j2.xml file in my resources package but when i run my mvn test it say No log4j 2 config file found. I also added this to my POM.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: I think you must put and log4j.xml in test folder. https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/configure-log4j2-for-junit/

Comment: Where did you put your log4j2.xml? Is it in src/main/resource folder?

Comment: yes i put my  log4j2.xml in the main not in the test @IgorKanshyn

Comment: @tsotzolas okay i will check that one Thankyou

Comment: I got this issue fixed by putting my XML in another folder named source inside the project and redirect my resources in my POM in that folder. :)